# Python: try/except OSerror errno 2

Tags: python, errno, eoserror

I'm writing a script where the user selects a directory and hits ok.

That I've sussed pretty easily, but I'm trying to sort error handling side, but it's not going to plan.

Essentially, I want to continue the script unless OSError Errno 2 is called.

at the moment, I have:
    import IOError
    ...
    ...

```
if ok==1:
  try:
    folder = selection
    myFunction(folder)
  except IOError:
    print "Select a folder, not a file"
```

I've tried using except without *IOError*, but that causes problems elsewhere in the script (In a different function completely)

Anyone have a suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to except `OSError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.isdir(folder)`

[Python - isdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by OSError Errno 2, but what ever error you want you can handle in `if` and ignore all the others with `pass` statement

```
try:
    folder = selection
    myFunction(folder)
except Exception as e:
    if "I/O operation failed" in e.__doc__:
        print "bingo"
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another way and more explicit would be:

```
try:
    os.remove(filepath)
except OSError, e:
    print e
```

However, depending on the frequency the Exception is called this method can impact speed.